# Improving access to private beta sites

Tags: discussion, usability, private-beta

It's been a while since I've been invited to a private beta and here are some thoughts on my experience with accessing the Sustainability private beta.

On my laptop I wasn't logged into the SE network. When I clicked on the invitation link and  went through to the landing page I was only provided an option to sign up for an SE account. I then clicked on the login option on the top banner I was then allowed to choose to sign in with my Google OpenID.

Just now I tried to access the site with my mobile phone. I was already logged into the SE network on a few sites. When I went to the new Sustainability site I was not given any option to log in, although I am already signed in to the SE network and I already have an invitation. I do understand that I wasn't following the invite link, but to me it shouldn't be that hard to sign me in, check if I'm invited and then pass me through. I'm sure there is a reason it was done this way, but again, it feels kind of clunky for a user with an invite to not be able to log into the site without having to open my email.

I then opened the Area 51 Sustainability page (already signed in to A51 account) to see if I could log in from there to save me the hassle of having to experience Hotmail on my phone, but clicking the "Visit the site now!" link from Area 51 only took me to the same page.

After opening my Hotmail account I clicked on the link and went through to the site. However unlinke on my laptop the mobile version took me immediately to a page where I was given options to choose my Open ID provied e.g. Google. Not sure if this is because I was already signed into the SE network or not.

No major dramas, just a bit awkward on the usability side.

Comment: This was all happening when you were trying to access the beta for the *first* time only, right? I.e., when you followed the link on your laptop, you didn't actually log in when you found the Google OpenID page, but instead tried to access it from your phone without the link?

Comment: @Laura - From my laptop was first time only. I then proceeded to log in with my Google OpenID. From the phone was later in day during the afternoon.